# Find all instances of "modelA" with no asscociated instances of "modelB" using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), the node.js module.

I want to [findAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance) instances of **ModelA** which have no associated instances of **ModelB**.

Each instance of **ModelA** [**hasMany**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-many/) instances of **ModelB**.

This is my current attempt which is not working.

```
ModelA.findAll({
  logging: console.log,
  where: {
    //- Where number of ModelB === 0?
  }
  include: [
    {
      model: ModelB,
      where: {
        //- Where doesn't exist?
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

I included the **logging: console.log**, to show that it needs to output a single mysql query that I can run elsewhere, which is why I'm not just filtering the users in the next promise in a promise chain after just returning all users.

Comment: Did you try `where : { yourForeignKeyName : null }` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
ModelA.findAll({
  logging: console.log,
  include: [
    {
      model: ModelB,
      where: {
        ModelA_id: {$ne: null}
      },
    },
  ],
})
```